# Propel - checking date

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, propel

Are function of Propel to checking date? For example i have in database:

2011-12-28 11:11

i would like get this if current date is higher of 1 days.
if current date == 2011-12-27 11:10 then should be return OK, and if current date == 2011-12-27 11:12 should'nt return OK.

I can get this for PHP and checking, but maybe i can checking this immediately in Propel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using the Criteria object (untested but should get you started):

```
$criteria->add(YourModelPeer::YOUR_DATE_COLUMN, strtotime("+1 day"), Criteria::LESS_THAN);
```